# React - Create tag dynamically from ES6 template literal with JSX

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, template-strings

I need to display a header element in a React `render` method where the level is dynamically set in the constructor:

```js
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this._checkedDepth = Math.min(6, props.depth)
    }

    render(){
        return(<h{ this._checkedDepth }>{ this.props.name }</h{ this._checkedDepth }>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HeaderComponent name="Header 1" depth="2"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

This should render `<h2>Header 1</h2>` with `name="Header 1"` and `depth=2`, but I get an error instead:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./HeaderComponent"

What am I overlooking?

I'm using `React 15.4.1`, `babel-preset-es2015 6.9.0`, `babel-preset-react 6.5.0` and running it in `Chrome 55`.

Answer (score 4):

> Each JSX element is just syntactic sugar for calling
>   React.createElement(component, props, ...children). So, anything you
>   can do with JSX can also be done with just plain JavaScript. -
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

So you can do something like this:

```
render() {
  return React.createElement(`h${this._checkedDepth}`, this.props)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering if I could use the JSX notation as shown but apparently this is not supported by React / Babel React preset.

Comment: @user3676597 (if you didn't know) babel has an online transpiler that highlights any errors which I find really useful for stuff like this - https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1&code=

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way of creating dynamic tags in JSX. React.createElement does seem like the only way for now

Comment: Ben to the rescue ;): Using Dynamic Element Names With The JSX Transpiler In ReactJS - https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2917-using-dynamic-element-names-with-the-jsx-transpiler-in-reactjs.htm

Comment: @user3676597 thanks for sharing, looks like you can do it

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit too late, but you can create a component or tag dynamically without using `React.createClass` with JSX putting the tag name in a variable and using that variable as you would with any other component.

In your case, inside `render`, you should have something like:

```
const TitleTag = `h{ this._checkedDepth }>`;

return <TitleTag>{ this.props.name }</TitleTag>
```

Note the first character of that variable must be uppercase in order to let React know that's a React component, otherwise a tag with the exact same name (not value) of your variable will be inserted instead.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized:

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'`
>   or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

There's no way to do this without creating that variable, so trying to do it on the fly as you do in your code will not work (compiler limitation).

Here's a fully working example:

```js
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    const depth = Math.max(Math.min(parseInt(props.depth) || 1, 6), 1);
    
    this.state = { depth };
  }

  onClick() {
    let depth;
    
    do {
      depth = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    } while(depth === this.state.depth);
    
    this.setState({ depth });
  }

  render() {    
    const Title = `h${ this.state.depth }`;
  
    return <Title className="title" onClick={ () => this.onClick() }>{ this.props.name }</Title>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <HeaderComponent name="Click Me!" depth="1"/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }

h1 { font-size: 4rem; }
h2 { font-size: 3.5rem; }
h3 { font-size: 3rem; }
h4 { font-size: 2.5rem; }
h5 { font-size: 2rem; }
h6 { font-size: 1.5rem; }

.title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.title:hover {
  background: #FFA;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```